# IE9 CSS Form Looks Terrible | FireFox, Safari, Chrome, & Mobile Look Perfect

Tags: jquery, forms, css, internet-explorer-9

The website I'm designing is:
http://www.centerforconfidence.com/addons/stop-tracking-ga/index.php?ct=disable

On All major web browsers, including: FireFox, Safari, Chrome, & Mobile... the website and the form looks perfect.

On IE9 and below, it looks terrible. The form has no styling, and for some reason, the whole content div is left aligned instead of centered.

How can I fix the form styling and content alignment on IE9 so that they look like they were designed to, without redesigning the whole website and form?

I am using the Azthetiks Product Launcher Platform for Wordpress 3.0+
Thanks!

Comment: Step 1: Make sure it validates (it does not)

Comment: I don't think you posted the right link...

Comment: (Just to nitpick: IE _is_ a major web browser - it has a bigger market share than any other browser...)

Comment: Yea, the link is correct. It redirects to the landing page So, why does the form not validate or style render on IE browsers, but works perfectly on all other browsers? FYI, IE actually has a smaller market share than FireFox now by 2:1 ratio, FireFox to IE

Comment: IE is still the largest browser on the market worldwide and in most countries, http://gs.statcounter.com/

Comment: Why do you hide an empty label next to the radio button and create a div with the date when it could be the label of this radio (and be clickable without JS)? The first text input is floating and absolutely positioned (a recipe for disaster or at least headaches on lesser IEs) when it could be a dead simple `display: block;` or inline with nearly 100% width (in px) and some margin.

Answer (score 1):

IE 9 is displaying the webpage in Quirks Mode. If you open the Developer Tools (F12) and select Standards Mode the form's button turns yellow and other style gets applied.

So you need to make sure IE chooses standards mode, either by using a different DOCTYPE or by other means.

Comment: Thanks!!! What Doctype should I set it to? I can probably get a wordpress Plugin to change it for me!

Answer (score 0):

FIXED. IE9 doesn't allow comments before the DOCTYPE declaration. I removed the html comments and it works perfectly in IE9 Standards mode. Thanks for the tip!